# How to limit who can merge code on a pull request in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I have a small team of developers that use bitbucket as our git repository.

I want to know how to limit who can merge code on a pull request in bitbucket? AND/OR force at least one approval before the merge can be done. Basically I am looking to force a code review.

As of now the creator of a pull-request (and everyone else) can not only approve but also merge the code in which can be an issue for quality purposes. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Bitbucket now allows for control over push permissions, branch deletion, and history re-writing. The full management instructions are here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-management-385912271.html

There still is not a way to force a minimum number of approvals however.

Comment: sit tight! Bitbucket is dead for the moment!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support-related question for the folks at Bitbucket.org.

Comment: @senfo support related questions still make sense on SO. Keep in mind that more than often, support related question are handled privately and might get ask thousands of time. SO help us find answer without having to ask them. There is no support team around the world that will beat that. Also, the question is `on-topic`. Check the faq

Comment: I have already looked through their support area, and user comments and questions. However if someone knows then they can share it on here. I always come to SO first for things like this. If I have to I will contact their support to see if its even possible to set permissions/force approval.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: what do you mean by "Bitbucket is dead for the moment" ??

Comment: This question should be reopened as defined in the help center. "software tools commonly used by programmers and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" This tool is solely used for software development. Not to mention the views and votes it has received mean it has found value here. Where else would this question belong?

Comment: 3k view in 2 years is barely anything on a site this big

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I want to know how to limit who can merge code on a pull request in bitbucket? AND/OR force at least one approval before the merge can be done. Basically I am looking to force a code review.

This functionality is not available in Bitbucket right now, but Atlassian's behind-the-firewall version of Git hosting has it.

Stash allows you to:

- limit who can change branches
- enforce a minimum number of approvals before merging pull requests (it can do a similar thing for Bamboo builds - i.e. the code must compile before it can be merged)
- reset approvals if a pull request changes

It's a curious asymmetry in Atlassian's own products.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer. Wish my question was not put as off-topic as i'm sure it will get deleted and there are others looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: Actually you can set now permissions here: Setting->Branch Permissions

Answer (score 0):

Answer from attlassian:

> Mary Anthony [Atlassian Technical Writer]
>
> Hi,
>
> So, a repository can have branches.  Within that repository, you can't
>   set permissions on a branch that are different from the repository. 
>   You can set permissions on the repository that would allow developers
>   to fork the repository and issue pull requests against it. To
>   configure this:
>
> ```
> Create a group on your account and call it  "developers".
> Give the group read permissions.
> Add all the developers to that group.
> Edit the groups on the repository and add developers.
> ```
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Mary

Here it is: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Work+with+pull+requests?focusedCommentId=321851850#comment-321851850

In other words, you can make your dev fork the project and issue pull requests from their fork. In your project , you can set the project to disallow public fork. I assume that they will fork the project and it will be hidden. That said, they will be able to issue pull request and edit their own repository. It looks quite akward but it should work.

I don't have the feeling that there is a good way to handle permissions on github/bitbucket and so on.

**edit**

Not really a solution to enforce it but still quite valid. Since approval of pull-request is quite optional. Doesn't mean that you're screwed and in fact, if I were you. I wouldn't try to enforce a system. The reality is that code review is important. Pull request makes it easier to review sets of commits.

I worked many months being the only one in my team to create/approve pull requests. The team in which I worked decided that pull requests was a waste of time and I guess that none of them did code review until I left. Last thing I heard is that my team mate is currently refactoring my code because he has no idea how it works.

What I'm trying to say is that code review shouldn't be enforced and your team should see it as a quite important thing to do. Each member of your team should work together and code review each others on their own. By doing code review, they will have the right to deny code that they feel is "ugly" or should be designed in a different way. Each member get to stay updated on what other devs are working and may not have much problem switching on anybody's work in case of illness, departure or death!

Enforcing the process in the system could be good from a manager's point of view. But I believe that having approval as optional isn't bad either. And then, the manager's job will be to check the merged pull request for the pull request with 1 or less approved person. Check who merged the pull request and who approved. Find someone to review the code anyway.

On the other hand, if a pull request is hanging around forever and nobody is reviewing it. It's the dev task to ask a mate to review it.

Comment: Sorry for not originally putting this in the question, but I had already read this in their comments. I don't want to fork because of the trouble it could cause with keeping the code in sync... But more importantly it still would not stop a developer from merging a bad commit in the fork. I am looking for anyway to set permissions, but if I can't then a way to not allow a merge until at least 1 (or more) approvals.

Comment: As far as I know the "approved" thing is completely optional. It only shows who saw the commit/pull-request.... There is nothing much you can do about it easily.